# How to connect to MSSQL DB with wamp64

Tags: php, sql-server, database-connection, sqlsrv

I'm using wamp64 as localhost for programming my php code.
But now I got asked to connect to a MSSQL DB.
I searched for answers on how to do it and found `sqlsrv_connect()` function.
When I call this function I get this error:

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\wamp64\

I'm not familiar with this, so could someone help me with instructions on how to fix this?
I also read that I need to install!? (I don't understand how to do this)

**My PHP version is 7.2.4**

This is my code:

```
$serverName = "server, 1433"; //serverName\instanceName, portNumber
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"DB", "UID"=>"USERNAME", "PWD"=>"PASSWORD");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
    echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
    echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

I also downloaded some **EXE files**:

> SQLSRV30.EXE, SQLSRV31.EXE, SQLSRV32.EXE, SQLSRV40.EXE

What do they mean? Which one should I have?
Please someone help me with this.

**Edit:** After trying the answer, I got this error:

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlsrv_72_nts'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it ~ PHP Version 7.2.4

pdo_sqlsrv : 5.3.0+11108

1.download the proper version sqlsrv and sqlsrv pdo

2.put it into XAMPP\PHP\ext folder

3.after that write the line into php.ini > module setting

extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts.dll

extension=php_sqlsrv_72_ts.dll

4.let's make a test for MSSQL still there is an error msg for recommending you to download ODBC Driver for SQL

5. Go to https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017 then download the proper file

(mine is Command Line Utilities 11 for SQL Server® X86)

6.fire the test.php again everything works!

Comment: In what folder do I need to put those files?

Comment: I got those files, added them to C:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.2.4/ext, added those lines to php.ini but I see no change

Comment: Still not working, did everything u said but from step 5 I don't understand anymore

Comment: It says Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlsrv_72_nts' c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.2.4/ext/php_sqlsrv_72_nts.dll

Comment: @JelleBotman - iirc wamp has 2 php.ini files: one for the CLI version of php, and one for the Apache server. Check in a path like: `c:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2/bin/php.ini` or something like that, and edit that one, and try again.

Answer (score 1):

I followed @SayedMohdAli's steps and Got this error:

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlsrv_72_nts'

I changed the name from `'sqlsrv_72_nts'` to `'sqlsrv_72_ts'` and It worked.

@SayedMohdAli thanks for helping me with this getting started. Solved it with your help.